# Using a variable in a Java case statment

Tags: java, switch-statement, compile-time-constant

I am making an expression parser for a calculator. The expressions will contain a variable, for instance, a user could enter "x + 2", or "y^2". I have a switch statement, and one of the cases in switch statement performs a certain action when it detects a variable:

```
case variableSymbol:
                    if (expression.length() == 1) 
                    {
                        rangeResult = x1;
                        break outer;
                    }
                    varFlag = true;
                    varPos = expresPos;
                    break;
```

Originally, I hard coded a value 'x' in the above case, but I would like to give users a choice as to which variable they use, so added a char parameter to the parse function, and named it variableSymbol. 
This is these are the parameters for the function:

```
public static ArrayList<Double> parseRange(String expression, char variableSymbol, double x1, double x2, double step)
```

But Java doesn't allow variables as cases in switch statements. Is there any way around this? Solutions that avoid rewriting the switch statement are the best, since it is several hundreds of lines long.Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Firstly, several *hundred* lines of switch-case needs immediate refactoring (just for being that long). Secondly, you can use `if-else` instead, if value is not known at compile time. But again, your `if-else` will also grow to hundred lines of code.. So, it's better to fix your design.

Comment: Your switch statement is several hundreds of lines long?!?!? I would definitely re-think your design, and come up with a better solution.

Comment: How about making some operator class and a factory that you pass the operator ? That way, it will be the operator class that will contain the logic inside of your case statement. This will simplify the readability of the code and the maintenance cost.

Comment: I'll look into code refactoring, but most of the statements are necessary. The calculator is geared towards evaluating integral and derivatives, so users need to be able to enter all the trigonometric functions, plus the exponential functional, the natural log, and log base 10, and it must be able to also do basic arithmetic operations on those functions, so I don't think I could make it shorter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that is not possible and doesn't make sense for a `switch` case; what you want can be achieved with `if-else`. The reason is because switch is typically implemented with look-up tables, being more efficient than `if-else`; but in order to achieve this the branching needs to be set-up at compile time.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would it wise to use an if statement in one of the cases? The cases before the variableSymbol case all fall trough, so it should be possible to say if( expresChar == variableSymbol ){ foo; }. But is  that too much of a hack

Comment: I would probably use a pattern matching (see Scanner class); or if the language should be more complex a parser generator such as ANTLR or JavaCC. If-else or switch is only good in trivial cases.